# heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: python, heroku

I push my app to Heroku. It was built and deployed but crashed. The app runs perfectly on local.

Comment: If your app crashed, then something is wrong with your app. Please provide more information about what your app does. Try to find a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that causes the same success on local build but failure on push.

Comment: The answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14322989/7246614) might help you.